# When scheduled with cron, ./azcopy does not run

Tags: linux, bash, shell, azcopy

There is a shell script in the location /file/location/azcopy/, and an Azcopy binary is also located there

The below command runs successfully when I run it manually

./azcopy cp "/abc/def/Goa.csv" "https://.blob.core.windows.net/abc\home\xyz?"

However, when I scheduled it in crontab, the "./azcopy" command didn't execute.

below is the script

```
#!/bin/bash

./azcopy cp "/abc/def/Goa.csv" "https://<Blobaccount>.blob.core.windows.net/abc\home\xyz?<SAS- Token>"
```

below is the crontab entry

00 17 * * * root /file/location/azcopy/script.sh

Is there something I'm doing wrong?
Could someone please help me figure out what's wrong.

Comment: You need to cd into `/file/location/azcopy/` in the script or supply the full path to `azcopy` ...

Comment: I'm sure that your script produces error messages on stderr. You need to find and check them.

Comment: Try to change `./azcopy` to `"$(dirname "$BASH_SOURCE[0]")/azcopy"`

Comment: cron debug hint:  add `>/tmp/cron.out 2>/tmp/cron.err` to capture the output, review, fix.

Comment: I was able to resolve the issue by changing the path to azcopy from ./azcopy to the full path to azcopy. Thank you very much @tink user1934428 Nic3500

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use root to execute the `/file/location/azcopy/script.sh`,you work directory is `/root` ,so you need to add `cd /file/location/azcopy/` in your `script.sh` script to change work directory. You can add `pwd` in your script to see the current work directory.